# Using swipe to delete function in swift on dictionary array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to use the swipe to delete function in Swift for my dictionary array and I keep on getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Dictionary<String, String>.Index." I am not sure how to change the data type and how to fix this.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return term.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let terms = Array(term.keys)
        let meaning = Array(term.values)
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = terms[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = meaning[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if editingStyle == .delete {
          term.remove(at: indexPath.row)
          tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
       }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tblTerms.delegate = self
        tblTerms.dataSource = self
    }
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTerm: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtMeaning: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tblTerms: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMessage: UILabel!
    
    var term: [String: String] = [:]
    
    // Actions
    @IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        if txtTerm.text != "" && txtMeaning.text != "" {
        term[String(txtTerm.text!)] = txtMeaning.text
        lblCount.text = String(term.count)
        tblTerms.reloadData()
        txtTerm.text = ""
        txtMeaning.text = ""
    } else {
        lblMessage.text = "No term or meaning entered"
    }
}
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Since term is a dictionary, you need to use `removeValue(forKey)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1641348-removevalue - You are treating it like an array

Answer (score 0):

It's not a **dictionary array**, it's just a dictionary.

Don't use a dictionary as data source because a dictionary is unordered. Better use a struct and an array

```
struct Term {
    let term, meaning: String
}
```

The appropriate data source array is

```
var terms = [Term]()
```

Replace the beginning of `btnAdd` with

```
@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    if !txtTerm.text.isEmpty && !txtMeaning.text.isEmpty {
        terms.append(Term(term: txtTerm.text!, meaning: txtMeaning.text!))
        lblCount.text = String(terms.count)
```

Finally replace `cellForRowAt` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let term = terms[indexPath.row]
  
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = term.term
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = term.meaning
    return cell
}
```

Now `terms.remove(at: indexPath.row)` works as expected.